# Отправить буфер POST запросом - ошибка TypeError

Tags: node.js

Нужно отправить  POST запрос с буфером. Проблема в том, что Node.js требует **либо строку, либо буфер**.

```
// Делаю стандартными средствами Node.js, так как нагляднее

const http = require('http');

const postData = {
  'encodedText': buffer
};

const req = http.request();

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

В итоге получаю ошибку.

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object

Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 1):

Отправьте в формате json, это будет строка.

```
const http = require('http');

const postData = {
  'encodedText': buffer
};

const req = http.request();

req.write(JSON.stringify(postData));
req.end();
```